# What am I doing wrong in this reverse traversion of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I've written this code that (should) iterate through the list `data` backwards, and delete any outliers (outside the max. and min. values). Code:

```
data = [104, 101, 4, 105, 308, 103, 5,
        107, 100, 306, 106, 102, 108]
min_valid = 100
max_valid = 200

for index in range(len(data) - 1, - 1, - 1):
    if data[index] < min_valid or data[index] > max_valid:
        print(index, data)
        del data[index]
```

This is supposed to remove the values 4, 5, 306, and 308; however it doesn't happen in my output. Output:
[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erIhX.png)

This isn't removing the number 4 from my list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 4 actually is getting deleted, and you'd see this if you inserted another `print()` after the `for` loop

Comment: Note that `[value for value in data if min_valid <= value <= max_valid]` is perhaps clearer.

Comment: `data = [x for x in data if x < min_valid or x > max_valid]` would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @chepner that appears to achieve the opposite of what is wanted

Comment: Right; should be `data = [x for x in date if min_valid <= x <= max_valid]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong, except you are printing the list before deleting the value.

Comment: I tried moving the print statement to outside of the for loop, and it works now (someone else also suggested this). Thanks for clarifying! Happy New Year and Merry Christmas :D

It doesn't let me make this the answer currently, but as soon as it does I'll do it. Thanks again.